# Heroku and npm list

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm

Is it possible to run npm list on two different heroku build versions?

My code broke between two different deployments. The error thrown is in a file that hadn't been touched for a while. We are suspecting some update of a dependency that's causing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why anybody downvoted but from the CLI you can run npm commands by:

heroku run npm list --app appname

Answer (score 0):

You can download compiled slugs for each build using Heroku API and then run `npm list` locally. You can check build id in Heroku dashboard, when you open build log.

Take a look at api docs and use client library [like this](https://github.com/heroku/node-heroku-client). First you need to fetch build info and extract slug id. Then fetch slug info using its id. From slug info you can further extract blob url. Download it and unzip or untar and you have it.